# qbo3 Task wizard

Tags: workflow, wizard, qbo3

We have a QBO workflow comprising the following steps:

- Task A
- Wait a day
- Task B

In most circumstances, users will:

- start from their worklist
- navigate to a Task A
- upon completion be returned to their worklist
- the next day, Task B should appear on their worklist

In a few circumstance, determined by the fields present in Task A, the flow should be:

- start from their worklist
- navigate to Task A
- upon completion:

  - if Foo = 'Bar', move to Task B for the same parent record,
  - otherwise return to their worklist

How does one accomplish this in a qbo3 workflow?

Answer (score 0):

Tasks, by design, will return a user to the referring page upon saving (or cancelling).

To cause a different page to render, use javascript to set the referring page to a different value.

From the Task GUI Designer:

- click on the `Foo` field
- in the Javascript > onblur field, enter code similar to the following (carriage returns are not required; just used here for readability):

```js
if (this.value == 'Bar') 
  qbo3.getObject(this).setReferrer('api/importform/summary?Object={{Object}}
&amp;ObjectID={{ObjectID}}
&amp;Method=RenderEdit
&amp;Template=Task B', this);
```

- click `Save`

Some notes / gotcha's with respect to the javascript snippet above:

- `qbo3.getObject(this).setReferrer(...)` changes the value of `document.referrer`
- the URL being passed is a relative URL, and causes a `Task` to be rendered
- the `Object` and `ObjectID` parameters tell `qbo3` to render a task on the same parent object as the current task
- using curly braces `{}` tell `setReferrer` to substitute the expressions with matching values in the current task (E.g. `Task A` and `Task B` should each have the same `Object` and `ObjectID`

  - because this data is being passed into `XSLT`, the curly braces must be doubled: `{{}}` so that `XSLT` does not attempt to interpret them
  - because this data is being passed into `XSLT`, the `&` must be `XML`-compliant; thus the use of `&amp;`